# How to make ButtonGroup visible dynamically from another command button?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, morph-x

I have action pane's MyButtonGroup's visible property set to 'no'.

What I want to do is to show (to set its visible property to 'yes') MyButtonGroup when I click Line view button.

I overrode Line view's method gotFocus:

```
MyButtonGroup.visible(true); 
super();
```

but I also want MyButtonGroup visible property to be false if Line view button is not focused / clicked

for this I overrode the lostFocus method on Line view

```
MyButtonGroup.visible(false); 
super();
```

so the lostFocus method "does not work", I mean when Line view button is not focused anymore 
 
MyButtonGroup remains visible.

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Never](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9296261/4509) use `gotFocus` or `lostFocus`.

Use the `clicked` method of `LineViewButton` and `HeaderViewButton` instead.
See my [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=n8HZTLas) for an example.

That said, you are on the wrong track, the button group would be better placed on the action pane directly above the lines.